# PWA project setup

Tags: magento2, pwa, react

I've just started using magento lately and I'm facing an issue initializing the project.
The documentation is listing two ways to do that:

1. Clone the pwa-studio project from github
2. Use the yarn scaffolding tool to create a sample project.

I need to know which of these two methods is the best practice and the future proof choice.